# Problemas para generar instalador de aplicaciones con Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project y VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-installer

Hace unas semanas formatee el ordenador, instalación limpia a Windows 10 1809 (no hay miedo!!). Instale el Visual Studio 2017 y le añadí el paquete "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project" para crear los instaladores de las aplicaciones.

Pues no hay forma de que funcione. Cada vez que intento generar un instalador se queda frito el VS, y solo queda CTRL+ALT+SUP, o pantalla en blanco "no responde y cerrar", y si lo dejo sin tocarlo, a los largos minutos tengo el error que pongo en la foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado en una virtual a hacer otra instalación, lo mismo (w10 1803 y w10 1809 por si acaso, aunque sin crystal reports ni algunos componentes añadidos) y si que funciona, de hecho tarda 0.1 segundos. También he reinstalado el paquete Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project pero no va.

He probado con una aplicacion "hola mundo" solo con framework 4.6 por si acaso, y lo mismo, nada de nada

Alguna idea antes de reinstalar VS, volver a formatear, etc.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionar el problema de la siguiente forma, me he ido a "aplicaciones y características" y he desinstalado "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (integrado)"

Y ahora genero los instaladores correctamente.